# Formatting output from RubyDatamapper similar to SQL

Tags: ruby, datamapper, irb

Running a `select` statement in psql returns output nicely formatted in a table:

```
mydb=# SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'foo';
  id  | login | first_name | last_name 
------+-------+------------+------------
 1000 | foo   | Dude       | HowdyHeyYo
```

However, I often run my database queries in IRB, and use datamapper to connect to Postgres. What's the best way to get the output formatted similarly to the above table when running a query like this using Ruby and Datamapper?

```
>> User.all(:login => 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

psql is formatting the output into the ASCII table layout. psql is the equivalent to IRB at that point, so you'd either have to write a method to call that would wrap your query and output formatted results, or use some IRB plug-ins.

Take a look at [IRBTools](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools) and, in particular, [hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb).

Comment: you rock! hirb totally does the trick. thanks for such a speedy response, and have a most excellent afternoon.

Comment: Hirb has a lot of cool capabilities. Seems like if it's structured data Hirb can format it.